# flex 4 - depth property not working as expected

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I am developing an isometric game.

I have a parent **UIComponent** (**WorldMap**). The player can choose **MapElement** s (game items) and drop them in the playable area **WorldMap**. This MapElement also is a UIComponent which contains child controls such as Sprite, Image, Label and custom Flex components to hold various information.

Now, I have written a logic to determine which one should appear in back and which one should appear in front in the Isometric area which I am calling **idx** (index) and I am seeting this value to the depth property of the **MapElement**.

I have added three components in the order shown in below pic and I have set the **depth** property each of them as 11077,11168 and 10630. If the depth property worked properly the 3rd item should have gone behind the 1st item but it seems like they are appearing in the order of they have added (default behavior)

If I am not wrong the depth value can be anything

Can some one help me?

I am aware of another solution using **swapChildren**, **swapChildrenAt** and and also **addChildAt** methods (which I don't want to use for my project specific reason) but I need to find out whats wrong with the depth

[image]

Comment: depth works only with Flex 4 components. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: mx.core.UIComponent is not Flex4 component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as I think, in your WorldMap component which, as you said, is UIComponent. Diving deeper to depth property shows that `depth` setter launches `invalidateLayering` method, which is empty in UIComponent and overrides with logic only in `Group` which is main container for every Flex 4 component. And here's example:
http://www.tink.ws/blog/flex-4-uicomponent-depth/

So, it looks like, you need to use at least `Group` or `SkinnableContainer` as your WorldMap in order to achieve depth property to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use UIComponent.addChildAt(child:DisplayObject, index:int). addChildAt adds a child DisplayObject instance to this DisplayObjectContainer instance. The child is added at the index position specified. An index of 0 represents the back (bottom) of the display list for this DisplayObjectContainer object.

Comment: Thanks for answer Tush, I actually forgot to mention that (updated now). I am looking for answer why **depth** is not working